# FORTRAN : maxloc

Tags: max

my data looks like

```
JAN    FEB    MAR    APR    MAY    JUN    JUL    AUG    SEP    OCT    NOV    DEC          
22.60  24.60  30.60  34.60  36.20  35.70  32.10  30.20  31.40  31.60  28.00  24.80  
25.40  27.60  32.40  34.60  36.50  38.10  31.70  31.40  30.30  30.20  27.00  23.90
```

and there are like hundreds of rows! I want to find a maximum value in each row and write it in different column next to data along with month

so my out put will be

```
36.20 MAY
38.10 JUN
.
.
```

I want to use maxloc function, but i have no idea how to use it!

Comment: Do some research.  Even if you just look at other Fortran questions on SO you'll find the answer.

Comment: i wouldn't have ask this question if it is that easy for me !! anyway thank you for help !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
index = maxloc(myTable(3,:))
print *, myTable((/1,3/), index)
```

It should select the highest value from the third row and display the first and third value at this index.